# nginx: [emerg] bind() to [ip]:443 failed (99: Unknown error)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

Absolute Nginx beginner here. I am trying to reverse proxy a HomeAssistant VM to `[hostname]:443`. However, when I try starting Nginx, it gives me the error:

> nginx: [emerg] bind() to [ip address]:443 failed (99: Unknown error)

My Nginx config is a follows:

```
http{
    server {
        listen [hostname]:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privatekey.pem;
        location / {
            root /home/www;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen hass.[hostname]:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privatekey.pem;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://[HomeAssistant instance ip address]:8123;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

What does this mean?
There is nothing running on port 443, so I'm stumped.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

I have tried killing any Nginx instances that might be running, but I can't find any processes.
I has also tried `nginx -s reload` and `nginx -s stop nginx -s start` but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just `listen 443 ssl` and specifying server name with `server_name`?  [The docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) say listen with a hostname is valid, but I'm not sure I've ever seen it used, and searching for your error turns up many other questions here with similar error msgs where the problem was related to `listen` with an IP/hostname.  Just a guess.